# Push adapter for more than one Worklight Application

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Is it possible to create one Workight Push adapter for more than one application in the same Worklight Project ?

if it is faisable how do I configure my project because I think that the push notification is recognised by the application name in the Android environment. So the push Handle will work just for the first application but not for the others.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications are not per application name. Why do you think this? Did you see it somewhere in the documentation?

See these topics:

- [Push notifications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification.html)
- [Sending push notifications to the device](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_sending_push_notifications.html)

What you could do is either write very generic code and make sure your subscriptions are unique to the app so they won't overlap and send a notification to both apps, or use multiple Event Sources - one for each app?

Comment: Regarding the application Name for the push notification is not mentioned in the documentation but the this the behaviour I got: I configured the push notification and it's working well,then I changed the application name in the file string.xml, the tag "app_name". After, when the application is opened and I receive a notification, the push handle is revoked. But if the application is closed and I receive a notification, when I click on it from the notification bar, nothing happen (the click shall open the application).

Comment: That's only because you are circumventing  the natural flow of an app; I suggest to verify that with actual 2 apps and not like that.

Comment: Actually, I created 2 apps and 2 Push adapters( each one has a different Event Source). when I invoke the submit notification procedure from the first adapter, the push is received by the first application, but doesn't work for the second application with the second push adapter.

Comment: What doesn't work? what happens? what does the log show? what differs between the apps and adapters? provide data

Comment: the log shows : "no subscription for the device" although the device exist in Worklight console (devices tab)

Answer (score 1):

The entity you declare in you adapter called EventSource. Any number of applications can subscribe to this event source. Now, the limitation is you'll be able to receive push notifications only in the app you've subscribed to push with. E.g. if you subscribed with app1 you'll be able to receive notifications with app1 only. In case you need to receive push notifications in app2 you'll have to subscribe separately. However there is nothing preventing you to use same EventSource (adapter) in both apps.

Comment: If I use the same event source, how the push adapter will distinct wether the request is from the app1 or the app2 to handle the right one ?

Comment: Adapter framework always knows which app request is coming from. This is controlled under the hood by Worklight, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by creating 2 Push Adapters, in each one I created an event Source.

After that,I created 2 applications in the same Worklight project, each one subscribes to a different Event Source but the both of them have the **same pushSender configuration** in the *application-descriptor.xml* file (same key and same senderId)

Notice that when created 2 event source in the same Push Adapter, the deployment of the adapter always fails, so that's why I created an separate adapter for each event source.